# NSUserDefaults only saving value for first key

Tags: macos, nsuserdefaults

I am having trouble setting up my app's defaults. I create a dictionary and I register that dictionary as the defaults. When I check the defaults system from the Terminal, only the first key/value appears to have been saved. The other are ignored.

```
NSDictionary *defaultsDictionary = @{@"Task" : @"Check mail",
                                     @"Interval" : @3,
                                     @"SoundSetting" : @3,
                                     @"Active" : @YES};
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultsDictionary];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; // Just for good measure
```

I can delete my defaults (using the proper method via the Terminal) and when I run my app the defaults are created each time for my app, so it's partially working at least - but only for the first value. Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-registerDefaults doesn't cause the defaults to be saved. It's what you use to put in the "default defaults", the values you want to be there if the user *hasn't* set anything. This is very useful, but it doesn't sound like it's what you want.

You probably want -setObject:forKey:

Also you don't need to call synchronize.

Comment: I am trying to set my app's default defaults but I didn't realize that it didn't save out to disc. (The fact that I'm able to retrieve a single value must be a red herring, I must be saving it out elsewhere). I guess that answers it, thanks!